# Remove first column of the datagridview when export table to pdf

Tags: vb.net

I would like to export datagridview table to pdf. But when I execute my application it takes the first column of the datagridview while I don't want the first column to be taken.

Here is the code that add the column. I don't want it to take the first column.

'Adding Header row

```
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns

        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(column.HeaderText, font12Bold))

        'cell.BackgroundColor = New iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240)
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER
        PdfTable.AddCell(cell)

    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normal for ... loop instead of a for each... and start from the second column (1)

```
For x = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
    Dim column = DataGridView1.Columns(x)
    Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(column.HeaderText, font12Bold))
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER
    PdfTable.AddCell(cell)
Next
```